# Using PowerShell to Close Firewall Port

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I'm doing some end to end testing of an application and I need to be able to close then open a port in Windows Firewall using PowerShell commands. I've found a script that adds a firewall rule to open a port, but I also need to be able to close the port.

Script to open - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/1173b550-9f19-495f-bf70-ea12e3a73866/using-powershell-to-open-ports-on-on-a-windows-2008-server?forum=ITCG

Is it possible to close the port in similar fashion? I need to close it first, do an operation, then re-open it and perform another operation. Hopefully the commands will work on Windows 7 (for testing locally), and Server 2008 and up.

Comment: FYI cmd.exe uses netsh advfirewall. dunno about powershell.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981391/delete-firewall-rule-using-powershell-on-windows-7

The link above contains solutions for `Disabling` or `Deleting` Firewall rules, for example:

Use `netsh` to delete firewall rules:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="$ruleName"
```

To disable a firewall rule:

```
function Disable-IncomingFirewallRule($ruleName)
{
    $firewall = New-Object -ComObject hnetcfg.fwpolicy2

    try
    {
        $rule = $firewall.Rules.Item($ruleName)
        $rule.Enabled = $false
        Write-Host "Firewal rule disabled"
    }
    catch
    {
       Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Rule does not exist"

    }
```